# How return a value for sample volume from last pivot in pine-script?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api

How return a value for sample volume from last pivot or where `rsi>75` in pine-script?

- And give an explanation of the use of arrays?

I try with an array but it doesn't work.